# Redbean find no datatype

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

i have a table called "aggregates" generated from Redbean, with these columns:

```
id      - INT(11)
user_id - TINYINT(3)
code    - VARCHAR(255)
sample  - INT(11)
```

but when I "exit" this code:

```
$aggregates = json_encode(Orm::exportAll(Orm::find('aggregates')));
exit($aggregates);
```

from php, I get this json output:

```
[
 {"id":"1",  "user_id":"1", "code":"baffdadsad", "sampleWeight":"100"},
 {"id":"2",  "user_id":"1", "code":"prova",      "sampleWeight":"900"},
 {"id":"3",  "user_id":"1", "code":"asdsa",      "sampleWeight":"120"},
 {"id":"4",  "user_id":"2", "code":"grana",      "sampleWeight":"89"},
 {"id":"14", "user_id":"1", "code":"get",        "sampleWeight":"1001"},
 {"id":"15", "user_id":"1", "code":"saghf",      "sampleWeight":"232"}
]
```

The **id** and **sampleWeight** fields should be **numbers**, why Redbeans dont recognize that? What can i do?

on Redbean documentation http://redbeanphp.com/import_and_export
I found this fraction of text:

> Since version 3.3: to only export a specific set of bean types: R::exportAll( $beans, true, $filters ); here $filters contains the **list of types** to be exported.

May be exportAll my problem?

Answer (score 1):

My issue can be solved by using the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK [predefined constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) like that:

```
$json_aggregates = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

that will output the right json with numbers instead of string-numbers, I'm not sure if is the best solution by the way...